# Docker - laradoc couldn't get logged in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have installed [laradoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SML3X.png) as per documentation but I am unable to login phpmyadmin.

here is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
 phpmyadmin:
  build: ./phpmyadmin
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    - MYSQL_USER=${PMA_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${PMA_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${PMA_ROOT_PASSWORD}
  ports:
    - "${PMA_PORT}:80"
  depends_on:
    - "${PMA_DB_ENGINE}"
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

and here is .env file

```
 PMA_DB_ENGINE=mysql

 PMA_USER=default
 PMA_PASSWORD=secret
 PMA_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
 PMA_PORT=8080
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Image attached, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to reproduce the error from the given info but this small setup works so maybe you can find what went wrong?

First bring your existing stack down and delete dangling volumes:

```
$ docker-compose down
$ docker volume prune
```

Start the following docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
 phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    - MYSQL_USER=${PMA_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${PMA_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${PMA_ROOT_PASSWORD}
  ports:
    - "${PMA_PORT}:80"
  depends_on:
    - "${PMA_DB_ENGINE}"
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
 mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    MYSQL_DATABASE: db
    MYSQL_USER: default
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

info (I had to use mysql5.7 otherwise I was facing [this bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14220):

```
docker-compose up -d
Creating network "test_frontend" with the default driver
Creating network "test_backend" with the default driver
Creating test_mysql_1 ... done
Creating test_phpmyadmin_1 ... done
```

I know I'm a bit 'messing' with the syntax + you can use the env vars too for mysql but I had to be quick.

Comment: Still not working, actually I am doing the same stuff but When trying to login with these details:
Server: mysql
User: default
Pass: secret

Comment: This solution above worked for me. Maybe first try to clean everything with docker system prune (so no dangling stuff is still behind)

Comment: I have logged in mysql while using command line but couldn't logging in from interface :(

Comment: Maybe the browser is caching something too? Can you use a private browser and really be sure to clean everything before starting the compose.